# How to identified modified elements in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This is my first array

```
$old = array(
1,2,3,4,5
);

$new(
2,4,5,6
);
```

I can do by using `foreach` command and then compare with two arrays. But the problems is I have to separate with which numbers were newly added and which numbers were removed.

And both array can be changed dynamically

**Edit:**

I have created a function

```
function get_diff($old,$new){
$small_arr = $large_arr = array();

if( count($old) > count($new) ){
    $small_arr = $new;
    $large_arr = $old;
}else{
    $small_arr = $old;
    $large_arr = $new;
}

$arr = array_diff($large_arr, $small_arr);

return $arr;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$old = array(
1,2,3,4,5
);
print_r($old);

$new = array(
2,4,5,6
);
print_r($new);
$removed = array_diff($old, $new);
print_r($removed);

$added = array_diff($new,$old);
print_r($added);
```

Use array diff basically

Comment: Wow... So simple, Working perfectly, Thanks xelbel :)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Multiple occurrences in $array1 are all treated the same way. This will output :

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But i have to find which elements were added, which are removed

Answer (score 0):

Also check these functions :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function get_diff($old,$new){
$small_arr = $large_arr = array();

if( count($old) > count($new) ){
    $small_arr = $new;
    $large_arr = $old;
}else{
    $small_arr = $old;
    $large_arr = $new;
}

    $arr = array_diff($large_arr, $small_arr);
    $values = "New values = ";
    foreach($arr as $arr_values){
        $values.=$arr_values.",";
    }
    $values.="<br/>";
    $same_arr = array_intersect($large_arr,$small_arr);
    $values.= "Earlier values = ";
    foreach($same_arr as $same_values){
        $values.=$same_values.",";
    }
return $values;

}
$old = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$new= array(2,4,5,6);
echo get_diff($old,$new);
?>
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wfm-jit)